# Discord.js login as user after 2auth

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord.py

How can I receive the user's information from an OAuth2 access token?

I tried doing this but it didn't work.

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
client.login('access_token');
```

I got the following error, though the access token was valid.

```
Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
```

On StackOverflow, I found some other solutions. But, it didn't work either.

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS], _tokenType: '' });
```

Answer (score 1):

OAuth2 does not work like that. You can't just log in to the user's account to access their information.
What you need to do is fetch the data from the API directly with the right endpoint.
There is a guide about how OAuth2 works right [here](https://discordjs.guide/oauth2/#a-quick-example).

Comment: Discord.js also has an [npm package](https://npm.im/@discordjs/rest) to help with that, e.g. handle rate limits and easily find endpoints.

Comment: @palm i dont see in documentation 99% functional with 2auth , only for bots. Where i can find documantation example login as user (he allow and make 2auth with full access scope) and send message from him ? or join to chat

Comment: As I said, OAuth2 does not work like that. You cannot log in as that user. You can only access their information but not modify it. You can make them join a guild through OAuth2 though. Here's [how](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#add-guild-member)